# Excel formula changes when I drag it down

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am running into an extremely vexing situation with Excel 2016. I have a formula:

```
=AL6&COUNTIF($AL$3:AL6,AL6)
```

I am using it to create an index column next to a defined range of cells and it concatenates the value in AL6 with the number of times that value shows up in the range. It works great and if I copy and paste the formulas for another row, adjusting the unlocked value, everything works great.

Here's my problem: when I drag down the formula, it completely changes it to: `=E7-WEEKDAY(E7)+13`   What?!?! How on earth does it come up with that? I use that formula 2 columns over and it's adjusting for the 2 columns. The original formula it's copying is `=C7-WEEKDAY(C7)+13`, but I'm dragging from above, not the side.

I have checked to make sure that formulas->calculation options->automatic is selected. I am beside myself trying to figure this out. Microsoft wants to charge $199 to help me with it. If anyone could help solve this very odd anomaly, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: would you include pictures? It's hard for me to visualize what is happening

Comment: 'above not the side' what do you mean by that?

Comment: No, thanks for checking into this guys. I just needed to restart the program. It was just bogged down. So sorry for the hassle.

Comment: @GowthamShiva you can't add "_resolved_" or similar indication in a title: that's against the principles of StackOverflow. So I'm rolling back your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You know what? So sorry for wasting everyone's time. I just had to quit the excel application and re-open it. My sheet is extensive with a lot of formulas being processed. After I did that, it worked just fine. If someone else runs into this same issue, I hope this helps.